# How to add a button in as

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flex4

hi I am just starting to learn flex and action script. can someone tell me I doing wrong in this code.

```
public function createBoxes():void 
{
    //create a Panel 
    var colorsPanel:Panel = new Panel(); colorsPanel.layout = "absolute"; colorsPanel.width = 250; colorsPanel.height = 250;
    //add the Panel to the Application
    addElement(colorsPanel);
    //create a red box 
    var redBox:Canvas = new Canvas(); redBox.x = 70; redBox.y = 70; redBox.width = 50; redBox.height = 50; redBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0xFF0000);
    //create a green box 
    var greenBox:Canvas = new Canvas(); greenBox.x = 90; greenBox.y = 90; greenBox.width = 50; greenBox.height = 50; greenBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0x00FF00);
    //create a blue box 
    var blueBox:Canvas = new Canvas(); blueBox.x = 100; blueBox.y = 60; blueBox.width = 50; blueBox.height = 50; blueBox.setStyle("backgroundColor", 0x0000FF);
    //add the boxes to the Panel
    var Button:spark.components.Button = new spark.components.Button(); Button.x = 120; Button.y = 60; Button.label ="removeG";
    colorsPanel.addElement(redBox); 
    colorsPanel.addElement(greenBox); 
    colorsPanel.addElement(blueBox);
    colorsPanel.addElement(Button); 
}
```

thanks

Comment: What's the **problem**? Doesn't compile? Doesn't ___?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? I just tested and it works well, so the problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: sorry , I dont know  what happened but it working now :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at it here... 
Are you using a Spark panel, or a Halo panel?
The way you can tell is by looking at your import statements.
If you see the line:

```
import spark.components.Panel;
```

Then you're using a Spark Panel.  In this case, you cannot set the layout property using a string. Instead you have to use an instance of a class that extends LayoutBase, such as BasicLayout. If, however, you see this line instead:

```
import mx.containers.Panel;
```

Then you're using a Halo Panel and I'm not sure what the problem is - you'll need to better describe the difference between what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.  If you're getting some kind of error, post the text of the error.

Comment: I use mx.containers.Panel; I Put a button on an application. Click on this button should load panel whit three different colored boxes and another button. And it doesnt happening i get Error #2032 in browser